# Unable to publish dependencies into private npm repository

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus, npm-publish, nexus2

I have created a private nexus repository to host my custom nodejs libraries. But when I publish my package, it doesn't publish any of its dependencies.

Steps:

```
npm set registry <registry url>
npm login
npm publish
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testpackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "safe-access": "0.1.0",
    "winston": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I get this issue when I try to install my package

```
npm install testpackage
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: ieee754@1.1.8
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /<path>/.npm/_logs/2018-10-04T11_25_36_719Z-debug.log
```

Is there a way to publish node_modules/all transitive dependencies into nexus? (Note: I will not be having internet access in production environment. Hence I need to download all dependencies from private repo itself)

Comment: If you don't have internet on the production environment how will you access thee npm package in the first place?

Comment: I want to download all the dependencies into my private npm. In that case it wouldn't need to go outside my vpn at all.

Comment: I see. I don't have a solution - it's a bit of an anti-pattern as you're not meant to store your dependencies, `package-lock.json` is there to verify the integrity and versions of your installed packages after a deploy / build.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

What you're describing is exactly what Nexus Repository Manager designed groups for but your internetless scenario removes that from the equation.
Your only recourse is manual upload.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue as follows:

I used a npm-group repository and added a npm-hosted repository and a cache enabled npm-proxy (Only this repository has internet access).
Steps to add new packages to the repository:
1) Add the repo to a dummy package.json 
2) npm install. (All the required packages get cached)
3) I point proxy-url to some junk url. (To avoid unwanted code to come into my environment).

Steps to use the repository:
1) npm set registry [npm-group-repo url]
2) npm install